# Attack a RSA padding scheme that appends zeros

Tags: rsa, public-key, padding

Imagine we implement RSA padding such that a number of byte zeros are appended to the message until its length is equal to 100 (i.e. 800 bits).

Also, let's assume that the public exponent $e$ is equal to $3$.

How can we break this encryption and find the flag with an approximate size of 150 bits?

Python code for encryption is implemented below.

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto.Util.number import bytes_to_long, long_to_bytes

flag = b"myflag{a_very_long_flag_is_written_here_with_many_chars}"

def pad(m):
    return m + b'\x00' * (100 - len(m))

key = RSA.generate(1024, e=3)
m = bytes_to_long(pad(flag))
c = pow(m, key.e, key.n)

print(f"e = {key.e}")
print(f"n = {key.n}")
print(f"c = {c}")
```

And a possible result

```
e = 3
n = 121093272852844700607509553526921787121889962911469990086240674763527007831445931610394898635953559914236289640814662391916827033328293150498629148607866791309196714798279731781969999612188854037695702368598356696238181576329571780699083311597719535685523585088583041029622133115035189452805449267132314669037
c = 118997582827921095335656050830593701790422781374666251790141811855117179467963374753099989931306799873562201419471821850445048120680741289536557129263492466647328606819668864981583844956072524787465657754032469369844885203438517971541452776224113666392886384116849073492807685359502765750768432203083431246434
```

Comment: May I ask how the question arises? I'd like to comply with site policy on answering questions like this: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Hint: Can you somehow express this string padding operation "more mathematically"? How does it interact with RSA encryption?

Comment: @DanielShiu - It's one of the exercises in a cryptography course I'm attending.

Comment: With the hint of SEJPM you must be able to solve it. Maybe you need another hint: RSA is multiplicative. What is the size of the flag?

Comment: @kelalaka - yes, I assume a hypothetical length for the flag, and then write the padded message as padded = r*m where m is the flag, and then by multiplying the r inverse in c, I can find what m mod n is. and since e is small, I can find the flag using cube root. This works for the given example, but not for the exact problem. I'm not sure what is wrong there

Comment: No, the attack is not the cube-root. The modulus size is 1024 bits and the padding is 100 characters implies 800 bits. Cube-root works if the cube of the message < modulus size. You need to solve by brute-force if I did not see it wrongly.

Comment: @kelalaka - How can I brute-force it when we don't know the length of the flag ?

Comment: This is why asked about the size of the flag. If it has 40-50 bits you can brute-force.

Comment: @kelalaka - the flag should be around 150 bits, so brute-force is not really practical. There should be another way

Comment: Reading the comments, did you divide by $r^3\pmod n$ rather than $r$? Check to see that the answer is small and then directly computing the cube root should then work.

Comment: @DanielShiu - Yes I've done it, not working

Comment: I've got it to work for me. There are a little over 630 bits of padding.

Comment: @DanielShiu - The example is updated since the flag was too short. Probably, you won't be able to solve it now using this method. The flag in the actual exercise is approximately as long as the flag in the new example.

Comment: Yes, that does make things a lot harder. I'm sorry; I can't think of anything when the flag is  longer than 45 or so bytes.